# Is there a pingdom-like service that has hosts in Asia and South America

Tags: network-monitoring, uptime, monitoring

I am looking for a remote monitoring service, similar to pingdom, that has more global reach. Right now pingdom only has coverage for North America and Europe. Does anyone know of a competing service that has more global reach to South America and South East Asia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that [**uptrends**](http://www.uptrends.com) is available worldwide and they have ping servers in 70 locations around the globe.

But of course, it won't be like the real Pingdom :)

Comment: Yes. It's very helpful and informative. Thanks for the tip

Comment: That was sarcastic, right?

Comment: i was sincere. I have signed up for the service to augment our pingdom. i now get timing from asia, india and brazil. exactly what i was needing.